# Is "all together" a valid alternative to "altogether" in US English?

Tags: british-english, world-english

I'm British. I am editing a document, and I was going to correct a use of "all together" where the author clearly meant "altogether" (as in "entirely"). But then I realised this might just be a British distinction... is it? Do Americans accept "all together" as a valid alternative to "altogether", i.e. "entirely"? (The document is for an international audience.)

Comment: There is a difference between  'altogether' and 'all together' in *British* English and both are perfectly valid in the right contexts. Please can you give a complete sentence.  P.S. 'altoghether' appears in Merriam-Webster http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/altogether so clearly it is not unknown in the US.

Comment: "Altogether" is perfectly well known and understood in the US as well.  There are contexts where either term will work, however, and one's judgment might vary based on which bank of the pond one is on.

Comment: @HotLicks It’s well-known that one’s *judgement* indeed varies so. :)

Comment: @tchrist - I gave up on that word a few years back.  I prefer "judgement", and believe it to be "more correct", except in legal contexts.  But the spell checkers always overrule me, and I got tired of fighting.

Comment: @HotLicks I also always spell it *judgement* and *acknowledgement* because the versions without the *e* don’t make sense to me.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I know "altogether" and "all together" mean different things in British, that's why I'm asking the question about whether they *also* mean different things in US English, because I don't want to 'correct' something that might actually be totally valid in its native language. (As far as I know, "all together" might have come to idiomatically mean "entirely" in the US.)

Comment: @callum, Why don't you just give us the sentence?  You are asking us to rely on your judgement (*the author clearly meant "altogether"*) but at the same time you say you don't know if the usage is correct. If you simply show us the text then at least we have the same information as you. Otherwise we just have to guess or cover every possible eventuality.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "You are asking us to rely on your judgement" No I'm not. You're just trying to answer a question I'm not answering. Even if you disagreed with me about what my author intended, that would have no bearing on my question about whether there is a regional difference in usage.

Comment: @callum, I was trying to be helpful. You will notice that your question has been put on hold (not by me). This is because you weren't specific enough. An authoritative essay on "regional differences between 'altogether' and 'all together'" would be a substantial research project.  Giving the context would have been simpler for all concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All together: in a group (a phrase of ALL) "all together, class"
Altogether: an adverb meaning completely, totally, wholly, etc. "I am flustered altogether"

Personally, I think the distinction is pretty straightforward whether British, American, Australian ...

Comment: Right: there is no difference in these that varies by region. It’s just a common blunder.